# Stack Overflow Documentation tab: is there a way to point a question and/or answer to a documentation topic?

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

Regarding the documentation (beta) tab, is there a way to 'migrate' a question and/or answer to a certain documentation topic?

Comment: If you want this to be added, you should make a question tagged [meta-tag:feature-request] asking for it, after [searching](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+%5Bdocumentation%5D+your+search+here).

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "migrate" and "point"?

Comment: Let's say I saw a question and answer that I thought would be a good addition to a specific documentation topic I'd try to migrate, move, copy it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Exactly what do you mean by "migrate" and "point"?
>
> Let's say I saw a question and answer that I thought would be a good addition to a specific documentation topic I'd try to migrate, move, copy it there.

There is a very large difference between *copying* a Q&A to Documentation and *moving* it there.

Right now, nothing stops you from manually *copying* answers to a Documentation topic. The only possibly non-obvious requirement is linking to the source question and giving credit to the author(s) of the answer(s) you are using, in accordance with the [CC-BY-SA license](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/attribution-required/). While it is conceivable that this process could be made in part automatic, one major complication is that, in all but the simplest cases, a fair bit of copyediting is necessary to convert an answer into an adequate topic, given the significant differences of form between these two types of posts. That, presumably, would make it necessary to create some sort of copyediting queue to process copied answers before they go live. (A comparable process elsewhere is ["dewikifying"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Wikibooks:Dewikify), which is the term Wikibooks uses for the unavoidable cleanup required by pages migrated from Wikipedia.)

*Moving* a question or an answer to Documentation, however, is an entirely different matter, and something that should not be possible at all. The reason why I oppose it is simple. My Stack Overflow answers are, to the extent my abilities allow, well-suited for the Q&A format of Stack Overflow. Furthermore, they form an organic whole in combination with the question and occasional companion answers they refer to. Now, even though I do not contribute to Documentation, anyone here is free to reshape part or all of my answers into a Documentation topic, as discussed in the previous paragraph. The topic, however, would in general not be equivalent to the answer, given the differences of form. Furthermore, nothing guarantees that all useful information in the answer would make it to the topic, or that it would be as well-suited to the Documentation format as the original question was to the Q&A format. Still, there is no harm in having some of the information in the answer available in a different format. Were the answer to be moved, however, all those differences would mean a very real risk of losing useful content. Additionally, I would have absolutely no interest in going over to Documentation to prevent avoidable losses by editing my "answer". While these considerations were made in first-person, it is not at all unreasonable to suppose they apply to the vast majority of Stack Overflow questions and answers. Therefore, a move-to-Documentation feature would introduce *a continuous net loss of useful content from the main site*, which makes it unacceptable.